# How does the control process of apache pass new connection to one of his children?

Tags: apache-httpd

I couldn't find any information on this topic.
Could someone point me in right direction?

Comment: You're assuming that it does...I don't know either way, but I don't think this needs to be the case.

Comment: Okay, my hunch looks correct -- it does not pass through a new connection.  The new connection is made by a child: http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/4_3Multitasking_server.html#SECTION00633000000000000000

Comment: Not apache related but [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGhlQomeqKc) is quite interesting and about how unicorn (ruby web server) does it.